# The counterpart of "facial" for head

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

We have the adjective "facial" for the noun "face", and I am wondering what the counterpart for the noun "head" is.
I could not find it on Google, and ChatGPT told me "cranial" which seems a bit different from what I expected.

Thank @Stuart F for the comment!
My original thought was to make a joke on myself who can have some kind of "head expressions" (corresponding to "facial expressions") because I am a bit bald.

And I am also happy to see that the vocabulary can be different in different contexts!

Comment: What context? Medical, cosmetic/beauty, CAM, in art, heraldry, armor, everyday language, in sports that involve the head (boxing/soccer/?)... Do you have an example sentence? (Cranial/cranium seems to refer specifically to the skull.)

Comment: Please don't cite those two things as having any credibility. Google just shows stuff.

Comment: Cranial refers to the skull in particular. The "head" is everything above the neck. Please supply a context where you'd want to use the word.

Comment: *follicly challenged*

Comment: @HippoSawrUs Thank you for this idiom!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Cranial* can be correct.

> Your attendant will apply the facial cream and give you a cranial massage.

To use *capital* in **that** case would not be correct.

- *Cranium* is anatomical

  > Those bones which enclose the brain (as distinguished from those of the face and jaws); the brain-case, brain-pan, skull — [OED](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=cranium)]
- *Capital* generally involves **loss** of the head

  > Involving loss of the head or life. Of an offence, crime, etc.: punishable by death; incurring the death penalty — [OED](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=capital)
- *Cephalic* has a specific biological sense (as opposed to purely anatomical) and tends to be used in combining forms with that meaning

  > Of or pertaining to the head, situated in the head; of the nature of a head. *Physiology and Biology* – [OED](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=cephalic)

  > Forming adjectives relating to a head or heads (in various senses) or skull, as cynocephalic, *adj.,* microcephalic, *adj.,* polycephalic, *adj.* — [ibid](https://www.oed.com/search/dictionary/?scope=Entries&q=cephalic)

---

Afterthought: If you used *capital* in "...and give you a capital massage," it would actually change the meaning completely to OED II.6.f (paywalled)

> Excellent, outstanding, first-rate. Frequently as an exclamation of approval. Now somewhat dated.

Comment: Where did the word capital come from here?

Comment: @Lambie (a) Latin *caput;* (b) the other answer.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry. :) Yes, a head wound is a cranial wound, right?

Answer (score 10):

In everyday language, the word *head* is often used as an attributive noun:

> The masseur will apply the facial cream and give you a head rub.

> Miss D. is waiting for her head transplant, so she has priority over Miss M., who merely needs a face transplant.

In more formal or academic or literary language, you could use *capital, cephalic*:

> Marie Antoinette was not in favour of capital punishment.

> Tricephalic people are superior to unicapitals.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!